# LiveData.observe(), a misleading name?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I don't understand why the Android team chose the name of method [observe()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E)), when it's purpose is to add an observer for this LiveData object. It seems to me that this is a semantically incorrect name. Because "observe" seems like it observes something, which is not true for this method. In my opinion, this method should be named addObserver().

So, my question is why did they choose this name? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> In my opinion, this method should be named addObserver().

It's not, because the intended API usage is not mirrored with `removeObserver`.

Subscriptions are automatically managed by the LiveData internally.

`observe` is a good name. Internally, the `addObserver/removeObserver` is handled inside LiveData implementation.

Comment: A method's name should refect what it does. If we have to rely on other existing methods to justify the name of a given method, then it's not a good name. In other words, I don't care about other methods of LiveData, I don't need to know about the internal working mechanism of LiveData, all I need to know is that this method adds an observer for it's LiveData object, so it should be named addObserver(someObserver). Moreover, the observer is the entity that observes the liveData, not the other way around, so when you write something like liveData.observe(someObserver), it is very confusing.

Comment: There is no "removeObserver" or "stopListening" or similar method that you have to call manually therefore it **is** a good name, as it is a 1 method api.

Answer (score 0):

if some entity has method `addObserver` so there must be `removeObserver` too. But in Android world `LiveData` is a lifecycle-aware component that automatically removes observer when activity is destroying. So in my humble opinion they right name for this method.

Comment: they do have a method named [removeObserver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#removeObserver(androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E))

Comment: it's opposite to `observeForever()`